# Self Hosting WCF service without name

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to host the wcf service on the following IP:
"http://MyIP:MyPort/" without service name using ServiceHost.

Now the host succeeded, but when I send any request it doesn't fire the function in the WCF service.

Is there any way to host the service like this?

Answer (score 0):

If by "without service name" you mean a URL with just an IP address and port (no URL "path", then the answer is yes you can host a service with a baseAddress as follows:

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:12080/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

- where localhost would be your IP or DNS and 12080 is your port.

The WCF Service method is found within the service using either

1. The OperationContract attribute "Action" property (SOAP):

   ```
   [OperationContract(Action = "http://<your action here>",
   ```
2. The WebGet/WebInvoke attribute "UriTemplate" property (REST):

   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "